# how to set Angular-datatables responsive priority?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am working on angular-datatables and trying to set responsive priority for last column according to [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.responsivePriority).
In angular I wrote it in following way

```
vm.dtColumnDefs = [
        DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(-1).withOption('responsivePriority',1)
    ];
```

But the above code is not working.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by updating responsive plugin from 1.0.1 to 2.1.0.